# Matlab double integral with heavily suppressed exponentials

Tags: matlab, precision, integral

I have recently been trying to calculate the double integral of the function`fun = @(v,x)(10^4)*0.648*(1+v*0.001).*(  exp(-2.83./( 10^-8+(sqrt(1+2*v*0.001)).*(x.^2)) ) -1).*(exp(-(v.^2)*0.33))`, in the range (-1000,1000) for v and (0,a) for x, where a is either a very large number or infinity. What I have found is that while in the case a = inf the value seems to be decently accurate (it reduces to a single integral which is less cumbersome to evaluate numerically), but if I integrate from 0 to a 10^9 and from 10^9 to infinity the integrals don't sum up to the correct value, with the latter one being zero. What I am really interested in is in the integral from 0 to 10^9, but these results make me wonder if I can trust it at all. 
In what I have done, I also had to use a large prefactor (10^200) in front of the function to "compensate" for the small numbers; otherwise the results were all nonsense. I have tried to use vpa, but with no success. What am I doing wrong?

Rob

Comment: can you please provide your code.

Comment: I'm not sure whether this is a programming question. It looks more like a numerical/math problem.

Comment: @obchardon I declared the function as written above and then entered 'integral2(-1000,1000,a,b)' with a,b appropriate extrema.

Comment: @MSalters I posted it here because I saw a similar question, which however didn't help me. Would you suggest asking it somewhere else?

Comment: I'm not a numerical math expert, so I'm afraid I don't know which Stack Exchange site would be more appropriate.  it's a fairly specific area of expertise, and I don't know where the real experts gather. The risk here at Stack Exchange is that there are too many non-experts who aren't aware they're missing critical knowledge. Such "answers" might be actively contra-productive. A good answer should be far more than a suggestion, it should explain what is going wrong and how that is sidestepped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your problem has to do with the different methods Matlab uses for different cases and the big numbers you are handling.

We can see your function with `ezsurf` just to have an idea on how does it behave.

[image]

So hint 1 is that the value is going to be a negative value, lets integrate over small limits to see an approximation on how much will it be.

```
integral2(fun,-100,100,0,100)

%ans =
%  -5.9050e+04
```

And assuming that the function tends to zero, we know the final value should be on the neighborhood.

Now hint 2:

```
integral2(fun,-1000,1000,0,100)

%ans =
%  -2.5613e-29
```

This doesn't make much sense, by increasing the range of the limits the integral basically became zero. After checking the [documentation of `integral2`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/integral2.html)

> 'Method' — Integration method
>   'auto' (default) | 'tiled' | 'iterated'
>
> Integration method, specified as the comma-separated pair consisting of 'Method' and one of the methods described below.
>
> Integration Method Description
>
> 'auto' For most cases, integral2 uses the 'tiled' method. It uses the 'iterated' method when any of the integration limits are infinite. This is the default method.
>
> 'tiled'    integral2 transforms the region of integration to a rectangular shape and subdivides it into smaller rectangular regions as needed. The integration limits must be finite.
>
> 'iterated' integral2 calls integral to perform an iterated integral. The outer integral is evaluated over xmin ≤ x ≤ xmax. The inner integral is evaluated over ymin(x) ≤ y ≤ ymax(x). The integration limits can be infinite.

Ok, so if we don't define a method it will use "tiled" if the limits are finite, and "interpolated" if they are infinte.

Could it be that if the range is too big, the tiles created by the "tiled" method are too big to accurately calculate the integral? If that is the case then "iterated" should not have that problem, let's check

```
integral2(fun,-1000,1000,0,100,'Method','iterated')

%ans =
%  -5.9050e+04
```

Interesting, looks like we are into something. Let's try the original problem

```
integral2(fun,-1000,1000,0,inf)

%ans =
%  -5.9616e+04

integral2(fun,-1000,1000,0,10^9,'Method','tiled')

%ans =
%  -2.1502e-33

integral2(fun,-1000,1000,0,10^9,'Method','iterated')

%ans =
%  -5.9616e+04

integral2(fun,-1000,1000,10^9,inf)

%ans =
%     0
```

That looks better. So it looks like the 'tiled' method is the problem with your function because its characteristics and the size of the range of the limits. So as long as you use 'iterated' you should be ok.

Comment: Now it works, thank you! It still gives me 0 if I try to calculate it from 10^9 to infinity although there is a small difference between the integrals from 0 to inf and from 0 to 10^9, but since they are so close it might just a matter of accuracy.

Comment: Yes, consider that after all, Matlab is doing numerical integration, not symbolic in this case, so the precision will have a limit, specially with ranges as big as the ones you are using